# How can I replace the content of a div when I drag and drop

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

How can I drag and replace the content when I drop; in this example:
http://jsbin.com/uvihox/5/edit ?

```
function allowDrop(ev){
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev){
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev){
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

Comment: you want to replace what?

Comment: the old content of DIV with the dragged images. see:  http://jsbin.com/uvihox/14/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
function drop(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    var s=document.getElementById(data);
    ev.target.appendChild(s);
    ev.target.src=s.src;
}
```

update your drop function like this. basically, you need to update the src of dropped img.
It works for now.

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manishmishra256/z32Pb/)

Comment: have you seen the sample site?

Comment: but you are already replacing your content fine. what you want??

Comment: if you drag and drop, remains the old content in the box.

http://jsbin.com/uvihox/14/edit